# Ansible gce module: How to set security groups (firewall)?

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine

How can one set security groups (firewall rules) for an existing network upon creation of a Google Compute Engine instance using Ansible?

The `gce` module doesn't seem to provide a key to pass this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [gce_net](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gce_net_module.html) module for security groups (firewall rules) for GCE.

Comment: This allows me to create the firewall, but how do I assign it to an instance upon creation?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
- name: Create instance
  local_action: gce
  args:
    name: my_instance
    tags: my_tag
    network: my_network
    ...

- name: Create a firewall rule for "my_network" and apply it to instances tagged with "my_tag"
  local_action: gce_net
  args:
    name: my_network
    fwname: my_firewall
    allowed: tcp:80,443
    target_tags:
      - my_tag
```